# First page of ViewPager not getting rendered

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` to be able to swipe between views. The problem that I am facing is, the first page does not render properly(only the static members from layout file get rendered), but the second page and further pages are rendered properly. Also, when I go to third or later page and then come swiping back to the first page, it gets rendered perfectly.

I know that `ViewPager` loads the first page as well second page in the beginning and does the same for every next page. Is this the reason why my first page is not rendered properly? I am making a network call on each page and the data returned is being displayed on the page.

Here is the code for my `Adapter`:

```
public class SlidingImageDetailAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    Context context;

    List<ImageDetailData> list;

    List<LatestComment> latestComments;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    GaApplication application;

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    TinyDB tinyDB;

    MixpanelAPI mixpanel;

    RestAdapter restAdapter;

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private static int radius = Utils.dpToPx(40);

    private String googlePlaceId = null;

    private String finalPlace = null;

    private String commentId = null;

    private String imageId = null;

    private String imageUrl = null;

    private boolean updateNeeded;

    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;

    ImageGalleryAdapter imageGalleryAdapter;

    ImageCommentAdapter imageCommentAdapter;

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));

    public SlidingImageDetailAdapter(Context context, List<ImageDetailData> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        application = (GaApplication) ((AppCompatActivity) context).getApplication();
        String API = application.getAPI();
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, application.getMixpanelId());
        final String token = tinyDB.getString(AppConstants.GA_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
            }
        };
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(API)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .enableAutoManage((ImageDetailSliderActivity)context, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "instantiateItem called");
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_image_detail, container, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        final ImageDetailData item = list.get(position);

        imageId = item.getPhotoId();
        holder.bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.deletePhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.locationIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.galleryList.setFocusable(false);
        holder.commentList.setFocusable(false);
        googlePlaceId = null;
        finalPlace = null;
        updateNeeded = false;
        commentId = null;
        imageUrl = null;

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getPhotoUrl())) {
            imageUrl = item.getPhotoUrl();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getPhotoUrl());
            ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                    .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setOldController(holder.image.getController())
                    .build();
            holder.image.setController(controller);
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(tinyDB.getString(AppConstants.USER_DP))
                .resize(radius, radius)
                .centerCrop()
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(holder.userDp);

        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(R.drawable.cta_button_post)
                        .into(holder.postButton);
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(holder.writeComment.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.cta_button_post_in_active)
                            .into(holder.postButton);
                } else {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.cta_button_post)
                            .into(holder.postButton);
                }
            }
        };
        holder.writeComment.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scrollToComment();
            }
        });

        holder.seeAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AllGalleriesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_ALL_GALLERY_PHOTO_ID, item.getPhotoId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //show and hide fab based on whether autocomplete textview has focus or not
        holder.autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    ((ImageDetailSliderActivity)context).hideFab();
                } else {
                    ((ImageDetailSliderActivity)context).showFab();
                }
            }
        });

        LogUtil.i(TAG, "Id of image = " + item.getPhotoId());
        PhotoAPI photoAPI = restAdapter.create(PhotoAPI.class);
        photoAPI.getFeed(item.getPhotoId(), new Callback<ImageItem>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final ImageItem photoDetails, Response response) {
                LogUtil.i(TAG, "photo api successful");
                DialogUtils.safelyDismissDialog(progressDialog);

                holder.locationIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getPhotoUrl())) {
                    imageUrl = photoDetails.getPhotoUrl();
                    item.setPhotoUrl(photoDetails.getPhotoUrl());
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(photoDetails.getPhotoUrl());
                    ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                            .build();
                    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                            .setImageRequest(request)
                            .setOldController(holder.image.getController())
                            .build();
                    holder.image.setController(controller);
                }

                if (photoDetails.isOwner()) {
                    holder.buttonBookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.deletePhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(photoDetails.getCaption())) {
                        holder.addCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        holder.updateCaption1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(photoDetails.getLocation())) {
                        holder.loc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        showAutoComplete();
                    } else {
                        holder.loc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.location.setText(photoDetails.getLocation());
                        showEditOrRemove();
                    }

                    if (photoDetails.getCampaignInfo() != null) {
                        showCleartripCampaign(photoDetails.getCampaignInfo());
                    } else {
                        showAddToExisting();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(photoDetails.getLocation())) {
                        holder.loc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        holder.loc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.location.setText(photoDetails.getLocation());
                    }
                }

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(photoDetails.getCaption())) {
                    holder.caption.setText(photoDetails.getCaption());
                } else {
                    holder.caption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                holder.time.setText(photoDetails.getTime());

                holder.username.setText(photoDetails.getUserName());

                holder.userFives.setText(String.format("%s Karma", Integer.toString(photoDetails.getUserKarma())));

                holder.numComments.setText(Integer.toString(photoDetails.getNumComments()));
                holder.numComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_PHOTO_ID, item.getPhotoId());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                holder.commentIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_PHOTO_ID, item.getPhotoId());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                holder.updateCaption1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        updateCaption();
                    }
                });

                holder.addCaption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        updateCaption();
                    }
                });

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(photoDetails.getProfilePic())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.feed_shape_profile_pic)
                        .resize(radius, radius)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .into(holder.profilePic);

                holder.profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_USER_ID, Integer.toString(photoDetails.getOwnerPk()));
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                imageGalleryAdapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(context, photoDetails.getGalleries(), item.getPhotoId());
                holder.galleryList.setAdapter(imageGalleryAdapter);
                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(holder.galleryList);

                latestComments = photoDetails.getLatestComments();
                imageCommentAdapter = new ImageCommentAdapter(context, latestComments);
                holder.commentList.setAdapter(imageCommentAdapter);
                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(holder.commentList);

                if (photoDetails.isBookmarked()) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.cta_button_bookmark_secondary_state)
                            .into(holder.buttonBookmark);
                } else {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.cta_button_bookmark_default_state)
                            .into(holder.buttonBookmark);
                }
                holder.buttonBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!photoDetails.isBookmarked()) {
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(R.drawable.cta_button_bookmark_secondary_state)
                                    .into(holder.buttonBookmark);
                            photoDetails.setIsBookmarked(true);
                            BookmarkUserAPI api = restAdapter.create(BookmarkUserAPI.class);
                            api.post(Integer.toString(photoDetails.getOwnerPk()), new Callback<ActionResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void success(ActionResponse actionResponse, Response response) {
                                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "bookmark successful");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "bookmark failed");
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(R.drawable.cta_button_bookmark_default_state)
                                    .into(holder.buttonBookmark);
                            photoDetails.setIsBookmarked(false);
                            UnBookmarkUserAPI api = restAdapter.create(UnBookmarkUserAPI.class);
                            api.post(Integer.toString(photoDetails.getOwnerPk()), new Callback<ActionResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void success(ActionResponse actionResponse, Response response) {
                                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "unbookmark successful");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                    LogUtil.i(TAG, "unbookmark failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

                holder.deletePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        updateNeeded = true;
                        FeedFragment.updateDelete(updateNeeded);
                        GalleryActivity.updateDelete(updateNeeded);
                        updateNeeded = !updateNeeded;

                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_delete);
                        dialog.show();
                        TextView cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView174);
                        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                DialogUtils.safelyDismissDialog(dialog);
                            }
                        });
                        TextView deleteButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView175);
                        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                DeletePhotoAPI deletePhotoAPI = restAdapter.create(DeletePhotoAPI.class);
                                deletePhotoAPI.delete(item.getPhotoId(), new Callback<ActionResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void success(ActionResponse actionResponse, Response response) {
                                        LogUtil.i(TAG, "image deleted successfully");
                                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Image deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        ((ImageDetailSliderActivity) context).finish();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                        LogUtil.i(TAG, "image could not be deleted");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                commentId = Integer.toString(photoDetails.getPk());

                holder.postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        postComment();
                    }
                });

                holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlternateFullImageActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_PHOTO_ID, item.getPhotoId());
                        intent.putExtra(KEY_SEND_PHOTO_URL, item.getPhotoUrl());
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        ((ImageDetailSliderActivity)context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                LogUtil.i(TAG, "photo api failed");
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed called");
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.imageView102)
        SimpleDraweeView image;

        @Bind(R.id.textView38)
        TextView caption;

        @Bind(R.id.textView39)
        TextView time;

        @Bind(R.id.textView45)
        TextView username;

        @Bind(R.id.textView46)
        TextView userFives;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView107)
        ImageView profilePic;

        @Bind(R.id.listView2)
        ListView galleryList;

        @Bind(R.id.textView57)
        TextView seeAll;

        @Bind(R.id.listView6)
        ListView commentList;

        @Bind(R.id.editText6)
        EditText writeComment;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView108)
        ImageView buttonBookmark;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView233)
        ImageView editButton;

        @Bind(R.id.textView151)
        TextView numComments;

        @Bind(R.id.textView82)
        TextView bar;

        @Bind(R.id.textView83)
        TextView deletePhoto;

        @Bind(R.id.textView79)
        TextView comment;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView116)
        ImageView userDp;

        @Bind(R.id.rel)
        RelativeLayout rel;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView131)
        ImageView postButton;

        @Bind(R.id.editText15)
        EditText editCaption;

        @Bind(R.id.textView184)
        TextView separator;

        @Bind(R.id.textView185)
        TextView updateCaption1;

        @Bind(R.id.textView186)
        TextView updateCaption2;

        @Bind(R.id.loc)
        LinearLayout loc;

        @Bind(R.id.textView115)
        TextView location;

        @Bind(R.id.locAuto)
        RelativeLayout locAuto;

        @Bind(R.id.autoCompleteTextView)
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

        @Bind(R.id.locEdit)
        LinearLayout locEdit;

        @Bind(R.id.editLocation)
        TextView editLocation;

        @Bind(R.id.removeLocation)
        TextView removeLocation;

        @Bind(R.id.scrollView)
        ScrollView scrollView;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView173)
        ImageView locationIcon;

        @Bind(R.id.textView5)
        TextView addCaption;

        @Bind(R.id.imageView11)
        ImageView commentIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

Comment: @VishalPatoliya can you explain why?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya it is not working

Comment: tell me one thing.. are you using tab layout. or fragmentPagerAdapter. if yes then i have solution for you.

Comment: @SagarChavada I am using neither. Just a simple `ViewPager` inside the layout for my `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

just add this method to your Class

```
 @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

it will render every time when you enter to particular layout. this is the override method of pagerAdapter.

Comment: It is not working. Even after doing this, `instantiateItem()` is getting called 2 times in the beginning, once for first page and once for the second page. And my first page is still not getting rendered.

Comment: that meant you first page is not in contact anymore..   try to add like this... list.size() - 1;

Comment: and yes.. it will be refresh the whole page so everything is getting called two time.. so try to clear your listview every time when you enter any page.